# Why does it not show the clients connected to the room in socket io and not send messages to receipent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, mern

I am building a simple chat application, I am using socket.io and tech stack is MERN.When user is authenticated successfully and when I get the tokens, I am setting user status online by the joining the room with users own id, so when other user wants to message the user, the other user will send the message to the room with user id. But here, When userA(sender) sends a message, it shows the clients(current socket through which the request is made) connected to the room(which is userAid),but not showing the clients connected to the userB(receiver). But when userB(now sender) sends a message, it shows the clients(current socket through which the request is made) connected to the room(which is userBid), but not showing the clients connected to the userA(receiver). So this is really confusing, the messages are not being sent to the receiver too, could someone help me?

```
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("user connected");
  console.log("socket id =>", socket.id);

  //  Join Room
  socket.on("joinRoom", (data) => {
    console.log("join room called");
    console.log(socket.id);
    console.log(data);
    socket.join(data);
  });

  socket.on("message", (data) => {
    console.log(socket.id);
    console.log(data);
  });

    socket.on("send-message", (data) => {
      console.log(socket.id);
      console.log(data);
      const clients = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(data.sender);
      console.log("clients =>", clients);
      const clients2 = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(data.receiver);
      console.log("clients2 =>", clients2);
      io.to(data.receiver).emit('receive-message', data)
    });


});
```